# Persist the custom view selected by the user while navigating between Document Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience, document-set

I have a document library in which I have created a custom view called Admin View and in the All Documents (Default view), applied a filter so users can see the items created by them only.

I have provided the link of the Admin View via email to admin users and they are able to access it successfully for root level but when they navigate inside the Document Set, the view changes to All Documents (default view) hence, admin users are not able to see the expected result. They manually need to again switch to the Admin View in order to see the documents inside the folder.

Is this by design behavior? Do we have any work around for this?

**Note: Everything is OOTB.**

Comment: I just tried the same scenario on my SP site & I am not able to reproduce this. View remains same even when I navigated inside folder/subfolder.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, yes my bad, It is a document set not a folder. Updated the question for the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the Welcome Page View (default view) for your document set. Follow below steps:

1. Go to library settings
2. Click on document set content type from "Content Types" section (Allow content type management from advanced settings if not done)
3. Select "Document Set Settings"
4. Select your Admin view in dropdown against "Welcome Page View" option
5. Click OK

[image]

Comment: But then if normal user will also be redirected to admin view right?

Comment: You mean user navigating to document library? Document library will have "All Documents" as default view & Document set details will have "Admin view" as default view >> for all users navigating to library/document set (either from site contents or from email link)

Comment: got it. But we can not persist the parent view right? it will always render the Welcome Page View for document set no matter from which view user is coming from.

Comment: Yes, right. It will persist the custom view only as you wanted.

Comment: My requirement is it should persist the parent view form where user is coming from

Comment: What will be the parent view when user is coming from email link? Also, your question states: "Persist the custom view"

Comment: For Admin it will be admin view for other users it will be All Documents. Persist the custom view selected by user meaning the view in which user is on the parent level that should be persisted

Comment: I don't this is possible as you can set only one default view for document set details.